# Custom status bar suppressed by SAP's default status bar

Tags: c#, sapb1

Am trying to find items based on item name.If items are present status bar stating "Item Found"  is displayed  else Item not found is diplayed.My problem is the status bar does not stay .its is overridden by SAP's default status bar operation completed successfully on button click.How can i prevent that.the code i used is

> public  SAPbouiCOM.BoStatusBarMessageType mt; mt =
>   SAPbouiCOM.BoStatusBarMessageType.smt_Error;
>   SapApp.StatusBar.SetText("Item not found",SAPbouiCOM.BoMessageTime.bmt_Medium,SAPbouiCOM.BoStatusBarMessageType)mt);

even tried this way it does not work

> SapApp.SetStatusBarMessage("Item not found",
>   SAPbouiCOM.BoMessageTime.bmt_Medium, true);

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the workout was to set
 **BubbleEvent  =False**